# Relational Algebra - Select with no predicate

Tags: sql, relational-database, relational-algebra

I know about relational algebra, but with regard to the `select` part of it, what should I say if there isn't any specific condition.

For example I have a `Hotels` Table and I just want to output that result.

Should I just use `σ(Hotels)` or do I need to put something like `σALL(Hotels)`???

I need your help!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What are you trying to achieve?  You want to output a table?

Comment: @lampej Yes I want to output a table!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an existing relation if you don't have any condition.

Examples:

Algebra: `R`

SQL: `SELECT * FROM R`

Algebra: `Hotels`

SQL:  `SELECT * FROM Hotels`

Returns every tuple in the Hotels table that you need. (No particular order is requested or implied.)

If you need to apply any condition only then use

```
σ <selection condition> (R)
```

Comment: I dont know because this situation is not defined as it is not needed.Use Reference for no condition and use σ when you have condition. Simple !

Comment: so just use (R) by itself then?